# Editing and adding a commit message to a file using the GitHub API

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I am using the [npm GitHub API](https://github.com/github-tools/github).

And I have four pieces of data.

1. the ref to the file I want to update
2. the path to the file I want to update
3. the new contents I want to be in this file
4. the commit message I want for this edit

Additionally, I can authenticate to the API, and have access to this repo.

How do I now edit this file and push this commit?

```
const GitHub  = require('github-api')

const gh = new GitHub({
  token: config.app.git_token,
}, githubUrl)
const repo = gh.getRepo(config.app.repoOwner, config.app.repoName)
repo.getRef(`heads/${config.app.repoBranch}`).then((response) => {
  const ref = response.data.object.sha
  const path = 'README.md'
  const content = '#Foo Bar\nthis is foo bar'
  const message = 'make readme foo bar'

  console.log('ref to the file i want to update')
  console.log(ref)

  console.log('path to the file i want to update')
  console.log(path)

  console.log('contents i now want in this file')
  console.log(content)

  console.log('commit message message')
  console.log(message)

  // how do i now edit and add a commit to this remote file?
})
```

I've tried using [.commit](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.1.0/Repository.html#commit) but, so far, have not gotten it to work, I don't understand how to generate the correct params to that function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Here's the syntax for how to do this:

```
const GitHub  = require('github-api')

const gh = new GitHub({
  token: config.app.git_token,
}, githubUrl)
const repo = gh.getRepo(config.app.repoOwner, config.app.repoName)
const branch = config.app.repoBranch
const path = 'README.md'
const content = '#Foo Bar\nthis is foo bar'
const message = 'add foo bar to the readme'
const options = {}
repo.writeFile(
  branch,
  path,
  content,
  message,
  options
).then((r) => {
  console.log(r)
})
```

I needed to use the [.writeFile](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/2.3.0/Repository.html#writeFile) method!